# Azure Functions: sudden CORS issue (after hours of copacetic development)

Tags: azure, azure-functions

Getting this error "Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource ..."

But I had been developing from my localhost:* just hours before. I did nothing to the application settings or CORS settings. Now I have a wildcard and it still doesn't work (above error).

I checked out {app}.scm.azurewebsites.net/Env.cshtml and I see:

```
...
APPSETTING_WEBSITE_CORS_SUPPORT_CREDENTIALS = True
...
WEBSITE_CORS_SUPPORT_CREDENTIALS=False
...
```

I don't know if these environment variables are correct or if they changed since my functions were actually working.

Answer (score 0):

I think that Azure App Service CORS is taking precedence over your application CORS settings. Quoting from another reply "If you enable one origin domain in App Service, and enable all domains in your Web API code your Azure API app will only accept calls from the domain you specified in Azure".

Here is the link to the other thread: [Enable Access-Control-Allow-Credentials header in Azure website (Azure App Services)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36860423/enable-access-control-allow-credentials-header-in-azure-website-azure-app-servi)

I hope that you find this answer helpful :)

Comment: I appreciate the answer re: its pragmatism, but part of me really wants to uncover why my application settings changed in the first place. And even still, I've used the wildcard and it doesn't work.

Comment: Add to this, I think I'm actually only using App Service CORS. I don't have any headers set in my actual Azure Function.

Answer (score 0):

While I've found a solution, it probably makes sense to address this problem anyhow.

```js
const proxy = require('express-http-proxy');
const app = require('express')();

const subdomain = '';

app.use(function (req, res, next) {

  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://localhost:1234');
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE');
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With,content-type');
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);

  next();
});

app.use('/', proxy(`https://${subdomain}.azurewebsites.net`));

app.listen('9091', () => {
  console.log('Proxy on http://localhost:9091')
})
```

Then just pass in `proxyUrl` as a parameter if you want to preconfigure HATEOAS links.