# azure removes Access-Control-Allow-Origin header returned from my app service

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, cors, identityserver4, azure-web-app-service

I have two services running on Azure :

- a **web service** ( angular app / expressjs )
- an **app service** ( aspnet core app )

All the **web service** does is query the **app service** for the following endpoint : `my-app-service.azurewebsites.net/.well-known/openid-configuration`

My **app service** is setup to allow CORS requests coming from my **web service** at the code level via the IdentityServer4 dll and as mentioned in many websites I DID ensure CORS settings were neither overridden by *web.config* or *azure CORS management page*.

These are my HTTP request headers :

```
Accept:application/json, text/plain, */*
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate
Host:my-app-service.azurewebsites.net
Origin:http://my-web-service.azurewebsites.net
Pragma:no-cache
Referer:http://my-web-service.azurewebsites.net/
```

And these are my HTTP response headers

```
Content-Encoding:gzip
Content-Type:application/json
Date:Fri, 05 Jan 2018 17:22:53 GMT
Server:Kestrel
Set-Cookie:ARRAffinity=da4c4ff244aae03ae3c7548f243f7c2b5c22567a56a76a62aaebc44acc7f0ba8;Path=/;HttpOnly;Domain=Host:my-app-service.azurewebsites.net
Transfer-Encoding:chunked
Vary:Accept-Encoding
X-Powered-By:ASP.NET
```

As you can see, none of the `Access-Control-*` headers are present. I have added a custom middleware to the asp.net core app pipeline to trace the response headers and I can clearly see them present.

So somewhere Azure is stripping off my headers and I have no more clues where to look now.

---

## Update #1

I forgot to specify that if everything runs on localhost, it works fine. But it does not on Azure.

## Update #2

#### My identity server 4 code

```CS
[...]
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens;
using IdentityServer4.EntityFramework.Mappers;
using IdentityServer4.EntityFramework.DbContexts;
using IdentityServer4;

namespace My.IdentityServer4
{
    public class Startup
    {
        private const string DEFAULT_DEVELOPMENT_AUTHORITY = "http://localhost:5000/";

        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            // [... add db context. identity framework, default token provider]
            services.AddMvc();

            // Cors ( not required, identity server 4 manages it internally )
            //services.AddCors(options =>
            //    options.AddPolicy("AllowAllOrigins", builder => builder.AllowAnyOrigin().AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyHeader()));

            string connectionString = Configuration.GetConnectionString("SQLServer");
            var migrationsAssembly = typeof(Startup).GetTypeInfo().Assembly.GetName().Name;

            // configure identity server with in-memory stores, keys, clients and scopes
            services.AddIdentityServer()
                .AddDeveloperSigningCredential()
                .AddAspNetIdentity<ApplicationUser>()
                // this adds the config data from DB (clients, resources)
                .AddConfigurationStore(options =>
                {
                    options.ConfigureDbContext = builder =>
                        builder.UseSqlServer(connectionString,
                            sql => sql.MigrationsAssembly(migrationsAssembly));
                })
                // this adds the operational data from DB (codes, tokens, consents)
                .AddOperationalStore(options =>
                {
                    options.ConfigureDbContext = builder =>
                        builder.UseSqlServer(connectionString,
                            sql => sql.MigrationsAssembly(migrationsAssembly));

                    // this enables automatic token cleanup. this is optional.
                    options.EnableTokenCleanup = true;
                    options.TokenCleanupInterval = 30;
                });

            services.AddAuthentication()
                .AddOpenIdConnect("oidc", "OpenID Connect", options =>
                {
                    //TODO: enable HTTPS for production
                    options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
                    options.Authority = DEFAULT_DEVELOPMENT_AUTHORITY;
                    options.ClientId = "app"; // implicit
                    options.SaveTokens = true;
                    options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                    {
                        NameClaimType = "name",
                        RoleClaimType = "role"
                    };
                });
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            // [... Some stuff before not useful for this snippet]

            // For debug purposes, print out request and response headers
            app.UseMiddleware<LogHeadersMiddleware>();

            app.UseStaticFiles();

            // Cors ( not required, identity server 4 manages it internally )
            //app.UseCors("AllowAllOrigins");

            app.UseIdentityServer();

            app.UseMvc(routes =>
            {
                routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });
        }
    }



    public class LogHeadersMiddleware
    {
        private readonly RequestDelegate next;
        private readonly ILogger<LogHeadersMiddleware> logger;

        public LogHeadersMiddleware(RequestDelegate next, ILogger<LogHeadersMiddleware> logger)
        {
            this.next = next;
            this.logger = logger;
        }

        public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
        {
            await this.next.Invoke(context);

            logger.LogInformation(
                $"------------------------\r\n" +
                $"*** Request headers ****\r\n" +
                string.Join("\r\n", context.Request.Headers.OrderBy(x => x.Key)) + "\r\n" +
                $"*** Response headers ***\r\n" +
                string.Join("\r\n", context.Response.Headers.OrderBy(x => x.Key)) + "\r\n" +
                $"------------------------\r\n");

        }
    }
}
```

## Update #3 - CORS on Azure service app is not set

[image: No CORS configured on Azure]

Any hints ? Thanks

Comment: post your code...it will help us to help you.

Comment: Hi @ElmerDantas, I did post some code but I am not sure it is relevant to the issue. I forgot to specify that when running on localhost everything works just fine !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@NoName found the answer to my issue on this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48230736/http-headers-removed-azure-web-app/48230859#48230859).

In a nutshell, https has to be enabled on Azure in order to work.

A warning from Azure in the logs would have been appreciated though. I wouldn't have lost days on this :S

Answer (score 1):

> CORS on Azure service app is not set.

Actually, Azure website is supposed to manage CORS for you. You just need to set the CORS on the Azure service App. I also find a similar [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36741567/cors-headers-missing-when-deployed-on-azure-web-app-azure-api) about it.

> The good thing is that you can completely disable this middleware and manage CORS by your own means, you just have to remove every single allowed origin (including *) from the CORS settings blade in the portal.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for taking time to look at it. As I stated, I do not want to manage CORS via the Azure blade hence my screenshot with no value in it (update #3). I want to let the identityserver4 manage it via its own configuration table.

Comment: If there is no value in the Azure portal CORS means that not turn on support CORS from server side. It is required if we want to use CORS.

Comment: This is from the link you gave me : `you just have to remove every single allowed origin (including *) from the CORS settings blade in the portal. Then you can use web.config or Web Api to handle it more specifically`. Which means that if I don't configure it on the azure interface, it will let my application deal with it. Or do I misunderstand it ?

Comment: Sorry for making you misunderstanding. Based on my experience, you could do that with web.config. It also will map to server side setting.

Comment: I eventually want to do it with web API but I actually tried with web.config, however it didn't work either. Do you know how to trace all the headers sent and received by the IIS in between my kestrel server on Azure and the client ? I can see a log of the requests but no way to see the header detail.

Comment: Have you refereced this [enable cors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api#enable-cors)?

Comment: This doesn't seem to be aspnet core link. But anyway in my case CORS is enabled via the IdentityServer4 code ( https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/blob/ec17672d27f9bed42f9110d73755170ee9265116/src/IdentityServer4/Hosting/CorsMiddleware.cs )

Comment: It still doesn't :) I'm just saying that CORS is enabled via web api from the identityserver4 dll.