# Http headers removed Azure web app

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, asp.net-core-2.0, identityserver4

I'm having issues with my web app hosted on Azure. This app is an identityserver4 application (asp.net core) used for authentication/authorization.

This app works locally but doesn't on Azure. By tracing the response headers coming from the server and what arrives to the final client. I can see that some headers "disappear".

To ensure it wasn't just related to CORS, I have added a custom header X-TEST. Again this works locally but gets stripped of when deployed on Azure.

Besides the CORS blade on Azure (and the web.config), is there any Azure options that might cause these headers to disappear ?

Thank you.

ps: This is related to [another issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48118901/azure-removes-access-control-allow-origin-header-returned-from-my-app-service/48179761) I have posted a week ago.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try https

(it might work
and google will say that your site is secure...)

Also, if you can inculde HTML, use  and  tags.

Hope this helps...

Comment: That's interesting.. I gotta to try that but I am curious to know why Azure would block some headers in http without notifying me somewhere ?

Comment: Very interesting, I can get the custom headers through now but still no CORS headers though.

Comment: I am having a similar issue and all the connections are HTTPS, but it looks like my BasicAuth header going to my web service is gone.